# Image properties display

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel i would like to know how to achieve the following:
I would like to insert an image into a cell then once inserted other cells in that row show the properties of that image eg. date modified, file name etc.
Thanks

Comment: To check the Image property,, Select the image & Right click it from the poped up menu click Property command. !! This much you need or any think else?

Comment: I believe Ashley wants excel to also paste in the properties data into the cells next to it if i'm reading this right?

Comment: Yes Myles that is correct. I would like to use the properties in a spread sheet. similar to how they appear in detail view in windows explorer.